# Running Mongoose Query Only If It Returns A Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to run a `findByIdAndRemove`-query.

The program always takes the success path and I don't know why!

I want it to take the `response.status(500).send(errorMessage)`-path if there is no record in the database.

```
async function deleteUser(request, response) {
  try {
    await User.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.id);
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(500).send(errorMessage);
  }
  response.status(200).send(successMessage);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `catch` block won't get called unless there is an error carrying out the query.

You won't get an error if `findByIdAndRemove` can't find a document.

However, Mongoose will return the removed document if one is found. It will resolve as empty if a document is **not** found.

So you could test if the returned user exists, and then throw an error to trigger the `catch` block:

```
async function deleteUser(request, response) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.id);

    if (!user) {
      throw 'User not found'
    }
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(500).send(errorMessage);
  }

  response.status(200).send(successMessage);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that it is best practice to catch your error in the callback provided by mongoose. checking that the result is undefined will not tell you what did go wrong and it doesn't tell you that the user does not exist anymore. For example, the user can exist but the query can fail for many reasons like network related problems.

If you want to go this way, you should query that finding the user again will result in an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?

```
User.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err){
```

});

Comment: I want to invoke an error if there is no user in the database

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [`strict option`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndDelete). This will `override` the `strict mode` of the `model` (if any). If you set `strict` to `throw` it will [produce an `error`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict).

Something like:

```
await User.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.id, { strict: 'throw' }, (err, user) {
    if(err) throw err
})
```

Comment: sorry, but there is no difference.

Comment: Did you provide a callback as well? Try what `() => { console.log(args) }` gives you.